# C language Function errors

Tags: c++, function

I use C language and I need to write a program with the different function. 
I have some problems with it and didn't find solution.

I have 2 kind of function.
This one

```
int X(int i, int k){
        int p, n;
    return p + (i-1)*(n-1) + (k-1);
}
```

In this function, I have the following error: error C2601: 'X' : local function definitions are illegal

The other one is

```
void Mode(){
matrix_entry temp;
temp=M[i];
M[i]=M[small_i];
M[small_i]=temp;
```

The problem is that matrix_entry, temp and M are undeclared identifier

Can you help me to find my mistakes?
Thanks

Comment: do you know about variable scope?

Comment: Also, `new` and `public` say it's C++, not C.

Comment: Looks like you have the right sort of bits (assuming this is C++ not C) , but you're probably glueing them together the wrong way. Show a complete example.

Comment: You haven't closed some curly braces. Looks like end of `Mode` is missing.

Comment: Another way to read the error message would be: "Unlike in Pascal, you can't define a function within a function."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> error C2601: 'X' : local function definitions are illegal

It sounds like you're defining a function inside another function; C++ doesn't allow you to do that. Move the definition of `X` outside the function it's currently in.

Another possibility is that there's another function immediately before `X`, and you missed out the `}` at the end of that function.

> The problem is that matrix_entry, temp and M are undeclared identifier But in my main I have this:

Firstly, types need to be declared before they're used. It sounds like this function appears either before the definition of `matrix_entry`, or in a different source file.

Either move the definition of `matrix_entry` to a point before anything needs to use it, or put it in a header and include that from each source file that needs it. That will fix the first two "undeclared identifier" errors for `matrix_entry` and `temp`.

If `M` is in `main`, then it's not available in other functions. You could pass it to the function(s) that need it:

```
void Mode(matrix_entry * M){
    matrix_entry temp;
    temp=M[i];
    M[i]=M[small_i];
    M[small_i]=temp;
}

int main() {
    matrix_entry *M = new matrix_entry  [10];

    //...
    Mode(M);
    //...

    // Don't forget to delete anything you new
    // (Better still don't new it in the first place, 
    // or use smart pointers if you must)
    delete [] M;
}
```

Comment: `Mode(m);` should be `Mode(M);`